How to open downloaded file in browser with Flutter Web?
I have a function that downloads files, but since there's no temporary directory as in Android/iOS, I don't know how to keep the file in memory and open it in a new browser tab. The file must be downloaded first and cannot be accessed directly through the url because headers with authentication token must be used in the http call in order to access files.
Here's my download function which works on Android and iOS, and only downloads files in Flutter Web:
  Future<XFile?> download({required String path, Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams}) async {
    Options options = generateOptions(await generateToken(), responseType: ResponseType.bytes);
    Map<String, String> headers = {};
    options.headers?.forEach((key, value) {
      headers[key] = '$value';
    });
    try {
      var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(path),
        headers: headers,
      );
      String mimeType = response.headers['content-type'] ?? '';
      String fileName = response.headers['content-disposition'] ?? 'File';
      String filePath = '${kIsWeb == true ? fileName : (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$fileName';
      XFile file = XFile.fromData(
        response.bodyBytes,
        mimeType: mimeType,
        name: fileName,
        path: filePath,
      );
      if (!kIsWeb) {
        await File(filePath).create(recursive: true);
        await File(filePath).writeAsBytes(await file.readAsBytes());
      } else {
        await WebDownloader.downloadBase64(base64data: base64Encode(response.bodyBytes), filename: fileName);
      }
      return file;
    } catch (e) {
      errorManagement(e);
    }
  }

How do I open the downloaded file once I have created the instance?

On my mobile project I use custom_tabs  package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs to open files on web view. I think you can do something similar without the need to download it.

I believe you can open files directly because you can pass a url with direct access to the file, but in my case it's not usable since the package you suggested doesn't seem to accept headers along with the path to the files (and I'm not sure it exists a package that does so)...

After the download completes, read the downloaded file's content as bytes using file.readAsBytes(). Then, create a Blob URL from the byte data using Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob), where blob is created with the downloaded bytes and its MIME type. Finally, open the blob URL in the webview. Following is an example method to show the file in the webview as a blob-
Future<void> openDownloadedFileInWebView(XFile file) async {
  final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  final blob = Blob([bytes], mimeType: file.mimeType);
  final url = Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);

  // Update WebView's initialUrl with the Blob URL
  setState(() {
    webView.initialUrl = url;
  });
}


I tried your solution, a new page is displayed with the correct mime type (for example if it's a pdf, it opens the pdf reader on Chrome), but the file looks corrupted ("Error. Unable to load the PDF document"), as if the Blob that gets passed is doesn't get created correctly..

can you please check if the file is passed to the method properly? as in check if the file & mime type is correct before reaching the proposed method or similar implementation.

I can confirm you that the file is correct, since on both Android and iOS that same instance of XFile is read and opened correctly. Also the mime type is correct, since in case of a pdf, the browser opens the pdf reader automatically
